# Converting multiple string inputs from user to Int, DateTime, and Decimal data types

Tags: c#, variables, type-conversion

Okay, so I'm a student online, in a programming class using C#. I have never programed before at all, so you'll have to dumb it all the way down for me.

This weeks assignment is:

1. Create a console application project and solution called `ConsoleStudentTracking`.
2. Create these variables with data type:

   1. `FirstName`: `string` data type
   2. `LastName`: `string` data type
   3. `StudentId`: `int` data type
   4. `BirthDate`: `DateTime` data type
   5. `Grade`: `decimal` data type
3. Use `Console.ReadLine()` method to get user input to fill in each of the variables in Step 2.
4. Use `Convert` class to convert user input (in `string` format) to required data type/format in specified in Step 2.
5. Write all values in these variables to the screen in this format:

   1. ---
   2. My name is LastName FirstName
   3. I’m a new student, and this is my first program
   4. ---
   5. My student id is: *whatever user put in*
   6. My birthdate is: *any date user put in*
   7. My Grade is: *any grade user put in*
   8. ---

I watched the videos my instructor sent out for us, Ive essentially followed the same steps just replacing variables. I will put my attempt at the code below, and here are the 3 error messages I am getting the following errors:

```
"Line 23: cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'"
"Line 26: cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'"
"Line 29: cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'decimal'"
```

I don't understand what isn't converting, or why. The video I watched did it just fine. Here is my attempt at the code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleStudentTracking
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string Firstname;
            string Lastname;
            int Studentid;
            DateTime Birthdate;
            decimal Grade;
            Console.WriteLine("a.-----------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your first name");
            Firstname= Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your last name");
            Lastname = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("b.My name is Lastname + ", " + Firstname");
            Console.WriteLine("c. I am a new student, and this is my first program");
            Console.WriteLine("d******************************");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your Studentid");
            Studentid = Console.ReadLine();         // line 23
            Studentid = Convert.ToInt32(Studentid);
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your Birthdate");
            Birthdate = Console.ReadLine();         // line 26
            Birthdate = Convert.ToDateTime(Birthdate);
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your grade");
            Grade = Console.ReadLine();             // line 29
            Grade = Convert.ToDecimal(Grade);


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @megz425, writing your first question is not easy. To get someone in the community to help you, you might want to format your question in a way that is easy to read and understand. To achieve this you can use the help icon in the editor, which is (among others) described here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85474/how-to-write-nested-numbered-lists. In addition you might want to describe more in detail what you already tried to solve the problem on your own.

Answer (score 1):

**It should be**:

```
23) Studentid = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
26) Birthdate =Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());
29) Grade =Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
```

**Full working Code** :

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleStudentTracking
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string Firstname;
            string Lastname;
            int Studentid;
            DateTime Birthdate;
            decimal Grade;
            Console.WriteLine("a.-----------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your first name");
            Firstname= Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your last name");
            Lastname = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("b.My name is Lastname + ", " + Firstname");
            Console.WriteLine("c. I am a new student, and this is my first program");
            Console.WriteLine("d******************************");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your Studentid");
            Studentid = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());         // line 23
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your Birthdate");
            Birthdate =Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());         // line 26
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your grade");
            Grade = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());             // line 29

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this mean that I need to remove the line that says "Studentid = Console.ReadLine();" before the conversion line? Because I tried both ways and now it gives me errors that int and decimal can not be converted to string type.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer from @akash here is some more information, *why* the errors occurred:

## Line 23: cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Your `Studentid` is defined as an `int`, wich means it can only store `int`egers (whole numbers like 1, 2, 3, 4, ...). However by using `Console.ReadLine()` you are asking the user to input some text (which is a `string`). You can look up the function signature at [Microsoft.Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/):

- [`Console.ReadLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline)
- [`Convert.ToInt32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32)
- [`Convert.ToDateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todatetime)
- [`Convert.ToDecimal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todecimal)

Even whe a user types in for example `1234` this is internally a `string` consisting of the characters `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`. In order to use it as an `int`eger you have to *convert* it. For this you use [`Convert.ToInt32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32) (in C# `int` and `Int32` are much like the same). The function expects a `string` which consists of only numbers and tries to convert it to an `int`.

So you could write the following code:

```
// take the input from the user as a string ...
string StudentidAsString = Console.ReadLine();         // line 23
// ... and convert the string consisting of numbers to an integer
Studentid = Convert.ToInt32(StudentIdAsString);
```

Note that the `Convert.ToInt32` function will fail (i.e. throw an exception) when the input is in the wrong format (i.e. it does not consist of numbers like 1, 2, 3, 4, ...).

## "Line 26: cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'"

Here the error is similar to the error before, except the `string` input cannot be cast to a `DateTime` which is also a data type in .NET and holds only date and time information. For this you can use [`Convert.ToDateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todatetime).
Again you could write the following code to better illustrate the separate steps needed to convert a date in string format to a `DateTime`:

```
// take the input from the user as a string ...
string BirthdateAsString = Console.ReadLine();         // line 26
// ... and convert the string to a DateTime
Birthdate = Convert.ToDateTime(BirthdateAsString)
```

## "Line 29: cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'decimal'"

Again the error is similar to the ones before. In this case the string number needs to be converted by [`Convert.ToDecimal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todecimal) to a `decimal` which is a data type that can also hold fractions of numbers (in contrast to `int`).

```
// take the input from the user as a string ...
DateTime GradeAsString = Console.ReadLine();             // line 29
// ... and convert the string to a decimal
Grade = Convert.ToDateTime(GradeAsString);
```

I guess these errors could have been solved by using your favourite search engine by just looking for `C# cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'"` (yielding a couple of 100'000 hits).

Hope that helps for your next assignment.

Comment: I changed lines 11-13 and defined the data types as string, and added "Console.ReadLine()" to lines 24,27,and 30. Now it tells me that int, DateTime, and decimal cant be converted to string. *insert facepalm here*

Comment: @megz425 There is no need nor is it desired to change the data types of your variables `Studentid`, `Birthdate` and `Grade`. You want them to be data types that are *not* `string` so you might be able to manipulate them (such as adding/substracting from it; all which is not really possible when dealing with `string`s). So the solution is to take the input from the `Console` (which always comes in the form of `string`s) and convert it into the appropriate data types. That can be done in either one line (as shown by @akash) or in separate lines by means of helper variables (here `~AsString`).